# Proving a sequence is null help?

Tags: real-analysis

So the problem is {sorry about the lack of proper mathematical notation}:
Given $|a|<1$, prove that the sequence $a_n = n|a|^n$ is null. 
I've gotten to the point of proving $a_{n+1} < a_n$ ultimately. Not sure how I can prove this is null. Help if possible?

Comment: Write it as $a_n=\dfrac{n}{|1/a|^n}$

Answer (score 2):

We have $a_n^{1/n}=n^{1/n}|a| \to |a|$ . Let $r>0$ such that $q:=|a|+r <1$. Then there is $N$ such that

$0 \le a_n^{1/n}\le q$ for $n>N$. This gives

$$ 0 \le a_n \le q^n$$

for $n >N$. Can you take it from here ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ratio test for sequences:

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{|a|^{n+1}(n+1)}{|a|^n n}=|a|\frac{n+1}{n} \to |a|<1$

Thus $a_n \to 0$

Answer (score 0):

It's not restrictive to assume $0<a<1$, because you always use $|a|$.

We can use a variant of Bernoulli’s inequality: if $t>0$, then
$$
(1+t)^n > 1 + nt + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}t^2
$$
which follows from the binomial theorem, because we discard positive terms.

Now write $a^{-1}=1+t$, so $t>0$, and
$$
\frac{a^{-n}}{n} > \frac{1 + nt + n(n-1)t^2/2}{n}
$$
hence
$$
na^n < \frac{n}{1 + nt + n(n-1)t^2/2}=
\frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{n}+t+\dfrac{(n-1)t^2}{2}}
$$